# error log with camera application with flask

Tags: python, flask, pythonanywhere, mediapipe

I am making an application where there is a camera with Javascript and another with python and mediapipe, on the local server it works perfect, but when I upload this to a server (pythonanywhere) it doesn't work, the second image is static (from python), there are some logs (error log and server log)
If you can help me I would appreciate it very much
Thanks in Advance
you can see my code

camera.py

```
import cv2
import mediapipe as mp
mp_drawing = mp.solutions.drawing_utils
mp_drawing_styles = mp.solutions.drawing_styles
mp_face_mesh = mp.solutions.face_mesh

def get_frame(entrada):
    drawing_spec = mp_drawing.DrawingSpec(thickness=1, circle_radius=1)
    with mp_face_mesh.FaceMesh(
        min_detection_confidence=0.5,
        min_tracking_confidence=0.5) as face_mesh:

            image = cv2.imdecode(entrada, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
            # Flip the image horizontally for a later selfie-view display, and convert
            # the BGR image to RGB.
            image = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.flip(image, 1), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            # To improve performance, optionally mark the image as not writeable to
            # pass by reference.
            image.flags.writeable = False
            results = face_mesh.process(image)
            # Draw the face mesh annotations on the image.
            image.flags.writeable = True
            image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
            if results.multi_face_landmarks:
                for face_landmarks in results.multi_face_landmarks:
                    #print("a",face_landmarks.landmark[0])
                    mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(
                        image=image,
                        landmark_list=face_landmarks,
                        connections=mp_face_mesh.FACEMESH_TESSELATION,
                        landmark_drawing_spec=None,
                        connection_drawing_spec=mp_drawing_styles
                        .get_default_face_mesh_tesselation_style())
                    mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(
                        image=image,
                        landmark_list=face_landmarks,
                        connections=mp_face_mesh.FACEMESH_CONTOURS,
                        landmark_drawing_spec=None,
                        connection_drawing_spec=mp_drawing_styles
                        .get_default_face_mesh_contours_style())
            ret,jpg=cv2.imencode('.jpg',image)
            asd = jpg.tobytes()
            return asd
```

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, request, make_response, render_template, Response
import numpy as np
from service import save_img
from camera import get_frame
app = Flask(__name__)
image = [np.fromfile('ejemplo.dat')]

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/capture_img', methods=['POST'])
def capture_img():
    msg,imgg = save_img(request.form["img"])
    image[0] = imgg
    return make_response(msg)


def generate():
    while True:
        frame = get_frame(image[0])

        yield(b'--frame\r\n'
        b'Content-Type:  image/jpeg\r  \n\r\n' + frame +
            b'\r\n\r\n')
@app.route("/video_feed")
def video_feed():
    return Response(generate(),
    mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')
app.run(debug = True, port=8000)
```

main.js

```
var video = document.getElementById('video');
// getUserMedia()Get camera footage with
var media = navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true });
//Pour into video tags for real-time playback (streaming)
media.then((stream) => {
    video.srcObject = stream;
    
});

var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
canvas.setAttribute('width', video.width);
canvas.setAttribute('height', video.height);

video.addEventListener(
    'timeupdate',
    function () {
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, video.width, video.height);
        var img_base64 = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg').replace(/^.*,/, '')
        captureImg(img_base64);
        
    },
    true
);



var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

//Captured image data(base64)POST
function captureImg(img_base64) {
    const body = new FormData();
    body.append('img', img_base64);
    xhr.open('POST', 'http://localhost:8000/capture_img', true);
    xhr.onload = () => {
        console.log(xhr.responseText)
    };
    xhr.send(body);
}
```

[work in local server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxTuH.jpg)

[work in pythonanywhere](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hckwx.jpg)

error log

```
2021-11-26 18:00:08,483: OSError: write error
```

server log

```
2021-11-26 21:29:47 Fri Nov 26 21:29:47 2021 - SIGPIPE: writing to a closed pipe/socket/fd (probably the client disconnected) on request /video_feed (ip 10.0.0.66) !!!
2021-11-26 21:29:47 Fri Nov 26 21:29:47 2021 - uwsgi_response_write_body_do(): Broken pipe [core/writer.c line 429] during GET /video_feed (10.0.0.66)
```

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not in comment).  It will be more readable and more people will see it - so more people can help you.

Comment: maybe first you could use `logging` to save more information in some file - i.e which line of code is executed and what you have in variables. Server may use multiprocessing and  every request  can run in separated process which doesn't shage values - so one request may open some connection but other request will not have access to this connection.

Comment: did you check if you don't have message in `JavaScript console` ?

Comment: your code didn't work for me on local computer because you have spaces between `\r` and `\r` in `image/jpeg\r   \n` in `generate()`. I didn't tested code but I would rather use `XMLHttpRequest` (or modern `fetch()`) to get new image instead of using `generator()`. I didn't test it on pythonanywhere but `mediapipe` may need something else to work. At start I see message that it uses `tensorflow`.

Comment: i changed my post, its work for me, you can check my page h4ckerman.pythonanywhere.com only if you refresh the page change the image, but its static, i dont have any erros in javascript @furas thanks

Comment: the only idea: mediapipe may need some other module or special hardware, or special privileges which you can't have on server (for security reson). I have account on `pythonanywhere` but never tested code which needs to access opencv or tensorflow.

Comment: or maybe `pythonanywhere` doesn't allow for streams like in `/video_feed` - and this would need to use `XMLHttpRequest` to get image directly from `capture_img()` and update `<img>`

Comment: Could you give me an example how to do the same with XMLHttpRequest ?, im so noob in Js

Comment: I test `pythonanywhere` using own code which `fetch())` to send image, use OpenCV to add rectangle and current time to image, and get it back in  the same `fetch()`, and use JavaScript to update image in browser - see if it works also in your browser https://furas.pythonanywhere.com . Source code on my GItHug `python-examples` in folder `flask` - file `app-4-.....py` (all code + HTML + JS is directly in one file) https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/flask/web%20camera%20in%20browser%20-%20canvas%20-%20take%20image%20and%20upload%20to%20server

Comment: I love it mate!!! i really need it for my titling project, im trying to separate HTML and JS but i get an error in js hahaha well, How could I send you a private message? @furas

Comment: you can find my email on GitHub [profile](https://github.com/furas) - `furas@tlen.pl`

Comment: i send a email thanks